# Using system tables to identify the columns of a table index in Sybase

Tags: sybase

Is there a means of identifying the columns of table index using systematically populated system tables such as: `syscolumns`, `sysindexes`, `sysobjects`, etc.

I have tried to use `syskeys` unfortunately this table is only populated by `sp_primarykey`.

So far I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
    i.name,
    o.name
FROM 
    sysobjects o
    INNER JOIN sysindexes i on i.id = o.id
WHERE
    o.type = 'U'
    and o.name = 'XXXXX'
      and i.indid > 0
      and i.status & 2 = 2
```

Comment: http://aspirantcoder.com/sybase-how-to-checkprogrammatically-check-if-index-contains-particular-column/

Answer (score 1):

I came up with the following solution - thanks to the comment by Phil:

```
SELECT
     distinct i.name as index_name, index_col(o.name, i.indid, c.colid) as name
FROM 
    sysobjects o 
    INNER JOIN sysindexes i on i.id = o.id
    INNER JOIN syscolumns c on c.id = o.id
WHERE
    o.type = 'U'
    and o.name = 'XXXXXX'
      and i.indid > 0
      and i.status & 2 = 2 -- Gives only system indexes. Skip it, and get all
      and index_col(o.name, i.indid, c.colid) <> null
    order by 1, 2
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of someone's sanity, munyengm has this correct but you may need to pass in the object owner as well if it isn't dbo or your current user.

```
**SELECT
     distinct i.name as index_name, index_col(o.name, i.indid, c.colid, o.uid) as name
FROM 
    sysobjects o 
    INNER JOIN sysindexes i on i.id = o.id
    INNER JOIN syscolumns c on c.id = o.id
WHERE
    o.type = 'U'
    and o.name = 'XXXXXX'
      and i.indid > 0
      and i.status & 2 = 2
      and index_col(o.name, i.indid, c.colid, o.uid) <> null
    order by i.name**
```

Answer (score -1):

In Sybase version SAP IQ/16, you can get list of indexes with following (table name my_table is case-sensitive):

```
select *
from sys.sysindexes
where tname = 'my_table';
```

Comment: The question refers to obtaining a list of *columns* in each index.  This only lists the actual indexes themselves, without the column names.

Comment: @max-vernon, In the version I use (SAP IQ/16.0.102.6.1386/20147/P/sp10.15) the sys.sysindexes table includes column names in the column: colnames. The table has following columns:  `icreator iname fname creator tname indextype colnames interval level_num`